# In LineageOS, how to remove the redundant navigation bar line?

Tags: samsung, lineageos, home-screen, navigation-bar

I flashed NikGApps on LineageOS 20 on my Samsung Tab S6 Lite, with Pixel Launcher replacing Trebuchet. I get double lines in the navigation bar.

[image: Doubled navigation lines]

The upper larger line seems to come from Google Pixel Launcher and is functional to show quick app drawer. The lower smaller one seems to be a remnant of the Trebuchet launcher and is always there.

Can I get rid of the small line?

Comment: I don't think it's a remnant of Trebuchet, but instead the UI framework of Samsung (and other ROMs) when using gesture navigation. The line appears on both of my Samsung and Pixel devices regardless of the home screen.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is there then some way (like Magisk module) to hide the short line?

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew T. pointed out, the redundant navbar line is from SystemUI and can therefore be removed by installing the Magisk module "Fullscreen/Immersive Gestures (Q-U)" and choose "Fullscreen" mode while installing.